# Querying Kafka Stream Store

Tags: ksqldb

Does the KSQL Editor in the UI, query all the KSQL Threads Store of an application at once, or just one of them ? How about the KSQL CLI ?

Comment: Can you explain more broadly what your question is? What is it that you're trying to determine about KSQL?

Comment: I create a table and just want to do select * from 'table'. I want to know if i am getting the result across all the topology instance store (Thread), or just one of them. I just want to know what i am seeing. I know how it work at Kafka Stream level, and how to query all the store exposed by your application Thread, but i don't know how KSQL work

Comment: KSQL works with topics. I do not think it is possible to query on stores if they are not backed up in topics.And the little I played with KSQL, I have the feeling that KSQL is only an "easy" way to write Kafka Streams apps, without coding in Java or Scala.